# Ruby return value inside of hash array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When in my ruby console, `a = first` is

```
=> <Ng::EntityConfiguration id: 15881, entity_id: 1, entity_type: "Ng::Company", key: "wpa2.psk", value: "[{"ssid":"LVL6-Staff","password":"987654321", created_at: "2016-11-08 05:13:04", updated_at: "2016-11-08 05:13:04", name: "WIFI/Level 6">
```

then `a.value`

will give you `=> "[{"ssid":"LVL6-Staff","password":"987654321","dhcp":"Enabled"}]"`

My question is, how to get the value when object is Password? because when I try with `a.value[:password]` got an error.

Comment: Is `a.value` a hash inside an array, inside a string? I tried to look at the original record and it doesn't match the pulled about value of `a.value`.

Comment: `first.value` also will return to you `=> "[{"ssid":"LVL6-Staff","password":"987654321","dhcp":"Enabled"}]"`

From original record, you can see it inside `value: ""`

Comment: Copying and pasting the code causes errors. Had to wrap it in single quotes, instead of double, to get the proper string to exist. Then it worked as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a JSON string, after `JSON.parse()` is an array with hashes.

```
>> x = JSON.parse("[{\"ssid\":\"LVL6-Staff\",\"password\":\"987654321\",\"dhcp\":\"Enabled\"}]")
=> [{"ssid"=>"LVL6-Staff", "password"=>"987654321", "dhcp"=>"Enabled"}]
>> x.last['password']
=> "987654321"
```